# How can i resolve the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server

I am using Heroku to run my server, and I am using 'cores'  at my backend side that wrote in Node.js.
I have these commands:

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options("*", cors(corsConfig));
```

in my client i am using vue.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: '"https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/',
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

when I am trying to get some data from my backend with Axios I get this message at my browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/random' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: The issue is that it is your development server and CORS to localhost will always be a problem.  Try using a different name or a non-127.x.x.x IP address.  It's a safety measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set ***config*** like this:

```js
const corsConfig = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

Comment: just a side-info: origin might also be an array of strings if you need to add multiple origins